# CPT defaults to single.php?

Tags: custom-post-types

This is more of a clarification question, but if I don't have a `single-CPT.php` script in my child theme, then will all my CPTs default onto `single.php`? I am just wanting to clarify more than anything. It appears that way on my local dev, but I thought this wasn't the case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, they will.

You will find the [WordPress template heirachy](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/) useful, particularly this graphic:

[image]

This shows how the templating system works - in particular, how WordPress will select the most specific template it can find, with fallbacks to the least specific (eventually, to `index.php`).

In your case, you'll see in there that `single-$posttype.php` falls back to `single.php`, then `singular.php`, then finally `index.php` ([direct link to single post section of docs](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/#single-post)).